# INTER-VLAN Routing with different Internet Access for each vlan

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, layer3, packet-tracer

I have a situation that needs some clarification.

I have three sites (1,2,3). The core switch do Inter-vlan routing. Site 1 and 2 must access the internet via ISP1, while site 3 will access internet using ISP2. All switches are Catalyst 3750. However, only the CORE is acting as layer 3 and the rest of the switches are L2. How do I make all clients in site 3 to access their own internet (ISP2) while still participating in inter-vlan routing with the core.

To clarify this, for e.g. vlan 10 in site 1 and 2 will access ISP1 and vlan 10 in site 3 will access ISP2. Inter-Vlan routing is working perfectly, but how to I restrict clients in site 3 to only access ISP2?

[image]

Comment: What is the core switch model and configuration?

Comment: All switches are CISCO Catalyst 3750G. However, only the core is L3 and the rest are L2.

Comment: You need to edit the question to include the core switch configuration.

Comment: When a host in Site 3 sends a packet to the internet, it looks as if the packet will first reach the Site 3 L2 switch, then go to the Core router, then get routed back to the Site 3 Switch and then goes to ISP2 over the Meraki. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @mere3ortal Correct

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Policy-Based Routing (a route-map with an access-list):

- Match all internet traffic from Site3 subnet.
- Set the IP address of ISP#2 as next-hop.

The access-list for this route-map should deny all traffic from Site3 to Site1&2, and permit traffic from Site3 to the Internet.

Comment: You may want to warn that PBR will punt to the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

By default policy based route will have priority on general route .. To fullfill your requirement PBR is best possible solution .

Route all vlan 10 traffic through ISP1 firstly . Then after further configured  policy based routing  in layer3 switch

`Source as== site3 host address`
`Destination as = ISP 3`

PBR configuration in layer3 switch will forward site3 traffic to ISP3 .